# How to detect and alarm data changes (abnormal or erroneous) from upstream

Tags: amazon-web-services, anomaly-detection

My application receives data from upstream system and blindly trusts the data and does processing. But, sometimes if the data from upstream was erroneous or abnormal, it causes impacts in the downstream system. For example, timezone for a group of US based workers in a site suddenly changed to Australia (by mistake from upstream)...
How can we detect changes on static data fields like this where the value doesn’t change often that too for a larger group and monitor for change detection and alarm.
Does AWS have any tools for this kind of change detection and alarming?

Comment: Not sure about the details of your system, but I'd use Kinesis Data Analytics or CloudWatch logs with filtering.

Comment: Thank you! Basically I need to compare the data with history and alarm the delta changes.